# PDO query error

Tags: php, pdo

Why this PHP lines do not work ?

I'm using PDO.

Thanks.

-

```
if($arr['target_action']=="new") {
    $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO ___Bookings VALUES ("", ":hotel_id", ":BOO_RoomId", ":BOO_ClientId", ":BOO_DateCI", ":BOO_DateCO", ":BOO_Rate", "", "", "'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'", ":BOO_Status")');
    $query->execute(array(':BOO_RoomId' => $arr['rid'], ':BOO_ClientId' => $arr['BOO_ClientId'], ':BOO_DateCI' => $arr['cid'], ':BOO_DateCO' => $arr['cod'], ':BOO_Rate' => $arr['BOO_Rate'], ':BOO_Status' => $arr['BOO_Status'], ':hotel_id' => $_SESSION['CurrentLogged_HOT_HotelId'])); 
}
```

Comment: Define "do not work"!

Comment: When in development, add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, if you're not already doing so.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Shouldn't that be  done in any case, not just during development?!

Comment: I've been told by so many times in the past 2 weeks of not using error reporting after development. I'm kind of in a "darned if I do and darned if I don't" situation. @ThiefMaster

Comment: You are not supposed to *show* errors in production (to your users). However, you are supposed to *log* them so *only you* can see them.

Comment: Exactly @ThiefMaster good point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the quotes around your placeholders.

```
if($arr['target_action'] == "new") {
    $query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO ___Bookings VALUES ('', :hotel_id, :BOO_RoomId, :BOO_ClientId, :BOO_DateCI, :BOO_DateCO, :BOO_Rate, '', '', :Date, :BOO_Status)");
    $query->execute(array(':BOO_RoomId' => $arr['rid'], ':BOO_ClientId' => $arr['BOO_ClientId'], ':BOO_DateCI' => $arr['cid'], ':BOO_DateCO' => $arr['cod'], ':BOO_Rate' => $arr['BOO_Rate'], ':BOO_Status' => $arr['BOO_Status'], ':hotel_id' => $_SESSION['CurrentLogged_HOT_HotelId'], ':Date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))); 
}
```

Also, why did you use string interpolation for the date?! Use a placeholder for that one, too!